# How to play base64-encoded sound in Python

Tags: python, audio, pygame, base64, ogg

I want to play a base64-encoded sound in Python, I've tried using `Pygame.mixer` but all I get is a hiss of white noise.

This is an example of my code:

```py
import pygame

coinflip = b'data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAACYZ...'  # Truncated for brevity
flip  = pygame.mixer.Sound(coinflip)
ch = flip.play()
while ch.get_busy():
    pygame.time.wait(100)
```

The pygame mixer works well if I import a wav/mp3/ogg file, but I want to write a compact self-contained program that doesn't need external files, so I'm trying to embed a base64 encoded version of the sound in the Python code.

NB: The solution doesn't need to be using pygame, but it would be preferable since I'm already using it elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you hear white noise is because you try to play audio data with a diffrent encoding then expected.

I think the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) is not 100% clear about this, but it states that a Sound object represents actual sound sample data. It can be loaded from a file or a buffer. Apparently, when using a buffer, it does expect raw sample data, not some base64-encoded data (and not even raw MP3 or OGG file data).
Note that there has been an [issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/556) reported about this on the GitHub repository.

So there are two things you can do:

1. Get the raw bytes of your sound (e.g. using `pygame.mixer.Sound(filename).get_raw()`, or for simple sounds you could create them mathematically) and decode that in base64 format.
2. Wrap the original (MP3/OGG encoded) file data in a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object, which is a file-like object, so the Sound module will treat it like a file and properly decode it.

Note that **in both cases, you still need to base64-decode the data first**! The pygame module doesn't automatically do that for you.

Since you want a small file, option 2 is the best. But I'll give examples of both solutions.

### Example 1

If you have the raw sample data, you could use that directly as the `buffer` argument for `pygame.mixer.Sound()`. Note that the sample data must match the frequency, bit size and number of channels used by the mixer. The following is a small example that plays a 400 Hz sine wave tone.

```py
import base64
import pygame

# The following bytes object consists of 160 signed 8-bit samples,
# which are base64 encoded, When played at 8000 Hz, it results in a
# tone of 400 Hz. The duration of the sound is 0.02 Hz, so it should
# be looped 50 times per second for longer sounds.
base64_encoded_sound_data = b'''
gKfK5vj/+ObKp39YNRkHAQcZNViAp8rm+P/45sqngFg1GQcBBxk1WI
Cnyub4//jmyqeAWDUZBwEHGTVYf6fK5vj/+ObKp39YNRkHAQcZNViA
p8rm+P/45sqngFg1GQcBBxk1WH+nyub4//jmyqd/WDUZBwEHGTVYf6
fK5vj/+ObKp39YNRkHAQcZNViAp8rm+P/45sqnf1g1GQcBBxk1WA==
'''

pygame.mixer.init(frequency=8000, size=8, channels=1, allowedchanges=0)
sound_data = base64.b64decode(base64_encoded_sound_data)
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_data)
ch = sound.play(loops=50)
while ch.get_busy():
    pygame.time.wait(100)
```

### Example 2

If you want to use a MP3 or OGG file (which is generally much smaller), you could do it like the following example

```py
import base64
import io
import pygame

# Your base64-encoded data here.
# NOTE: Do NOT include the "data:audio/ogg;base64," part.
base64_encoded_sound_file_data = b'T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAACY...'  # Truncated for brevity

pygame.mixer.init()
sound_file_data = base64.b64decode(base64_encoded_sound_file_data)
assert sound_file_data.startswith(b'OggS')  # just to prove it is an Ogg Vorbis file
sound_file = io.BytesIO(sound_file_data)
# The following line will only work with VALID data. With above example data it will fail.
sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(sound_file)
ch = sound.play()
while ch.get_busy():
    pygame.time.wait(100)
```

I would have preferred to use real data in this example as well, but the smallest useful Ogg file I could find was 9 kB, which would add about 120 long lines of data, and I don't think that is appropriate for a Stack Overflow answer. But if you replace it with your own data (which is hopefully a valid Ogg audio file), it should work.